# FB.api('/photos') works outside of Facebook app, but not WITHIN the app

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am POSTING a photo the a users facebook using the JS SDK via FB.api("/photos","post",etc)...

I can successfully do this in a dedicated URL outside of the FB app. but when attempting to post within the app, I get this error:

```
Error occured:{"message":"An unknown error has occurred.","type":"OAuthException","code":1}
```

I have a valid access token each time.  Can anyone help please?? thank you!

```
    FB.api('/photos', 'post', {
        message: 'Use the Sephora Framework app to transform pictures from your life into one extraordinary story. http://seph.me/SmcbkM',
        access_token: Sephora.accessToken,
        url: imgURL
    }, function (response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
            alert('Error occured:' + JSON.stringify(response.error));
        } else {
                        FB.api('/'+response.id, function(response){
                            storeSubmission(response.images[1].source);
                        });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You have used the wrong end-point: `/photos`.

You have to specify the user-id or the current user in session to which profile you want to add the photo.

So the correct call is: `/me/photos`

Comment: i can successfully use /photos outside of the app... regardless i did try /me/photos and still got the same error

Comment: What exactly did you mean by `outside the app`- can you elaborate on this pls

Comment: Of couse without mentioning the correct end point `/me/photos` this will not work. You can test it here: http://developers.facebook.com

Comment: "outside the app" meaning not iframed inside the FB app.  the source URL is sephoraframeworkapp.com ...that will work to upload a photo.... but uploading/posting a photo from the FB app that pulls in sephoraframeworkapp.com ...that does not work

Comment: Then `access_token` must be wrong. Remove the parameter `access_token` and then try. Its not required since user is already logged-in to your app. Also, make sure you have `user_photos` perms

Comment: removed access_token and user_photos is confirmed already there, same error :/

Comment: the app lives here: https://www.facebook.com/Sephora/app_428998810497320 it pulls in the site: sephoraframeworkapp.com ...pls let me know any thoughts!

Comment: I cant proceed after step-2 (both canvas and web app). Also it didnt asked for the authorization till step-2?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/Sephora/app_428998810497320 does not let you passed step-2? it should/does for me?

Comment: I mean I selected a picture, what after that? nothing happens. Also  I cant see auth dialog once, where have you implemented that?